# Dash callback returning 403 forbidden

Tags: python-3.x, flask, plotly-dash

Recently moved my application into a Dash/Flask embedded app. I have discovered that certain callbacks are failing with "403 forbidden".

If I run the app in the usual development mode off my laptop (web server less) with app.run_server everything works as expected. It is only when running in the new embedded app.

I cannot find any explanation. Maybe CSRF? What would cause a callback to return a 403?

One odd commonality is that the callbacks that have this problem are only ones that take a dash data table "data" as input.

Edit:
Further review with inspector shows that a POST to _dash-update-component is returning the 403 with the following data in the response:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the load balancer in our new environment. If anyone runs into this in the future and your using an Amazon elastic load balancer take a look at your WAF policies.